# JUnit test in Kotlin

Tags: junit, kotlin

**Warning: I'm a huge noob to TDD and Kotlin.**

I've found good code snippets on the web for writing JUnit tests in Kotlin, but when I copy and paste, IntelliJ does not automagically import `kotlin.test.*` or `org.junit.Test`.  Typically in Eclipse, when I copy and paste code snippets like this, the IDE can figure out where these libraries are in my underlying java install.  Figured Kotlin/IntelliJ would be the same.

In the below screenshot, any idea why I cannot import test libraries?  Do they need to be added explicitly to my path?  Do I need to put these under a `test`, rather than the `src` folder?

Thanks [image]

Comment: And hint: no need for a screenshot - you could as well just post the code and the error message as text ... just saying.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I think for questions involving an editor, it's easier to show the editor's color highlighting and so forth instead of just my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JUnit isn't in your project classpath, so IntelliJ can't find it's packages.

Follow the steps outlined in this answer: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project), choosing libraries and then junit.

Comment: Hmm, so JUnit isn't something that's kind of "baked in" and visible to any new project?

Comment: @AdamHughes Why should that be?

Comment: Hmm, well I thought at least `kotlin.test` import would be standard.  `junit` I guess it makes sense, but somehow I figured it'd be in the standard library. Guess I'm mistaken though, wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: kotlin-test is a separate artifact as well: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test